# Evading including headers to the .h file

Tags: c++, prototype, header-files

I have been told to not include too many classes in the .header if I can evade it, and instead, include them in the .cpp. To do it, they told my to create prototypes classes like:

```
class abc;
```

instead of:

```
include "abc.h"
```

But this just in case the abc class is not being used as attribute or a return value. If it's a parameter, I can use the prototype... Why is this?

Also, why is so bad to include so many headers in the .h file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it's a parameter, I can use the prototype... Why is this?

You can use a forward declaration whenever yo do not need access to the inner structure of the declared class, e.g. when you declare a pointer, a reference, or passed it as parameter. You cannot use a forward declaration to inherit a class, call any of its member functions or access its members, or declare members of non pointer/reference type: this is because the inner structure of the class must be known to the compiler in order to do any of the above.

> why is so bad to include so many headers in the .h file?

This is not universally "bad" in itself, but with many compilers it may slow down the compilation process, so it is typical to minimize your inclusions. Modern compilers have useful features (such as precompiled headers) to minimize the impact, so using forward declarations where you can becomes more an aesthetic choice than a practical matter.

Comment: Precompiled headers do help, but don't solve the problem of large dependency trees that require substantial parts of the code base to be recompiled unnecessarily if one of the headers is modified. Using a precompiled header you'd simply speed up the rebuild, you don't prevent it.

Comment: Ok but, if the prototype class is used as an attribute, I can't use a prototype and I have to do the include, or at least is what I have been told. Why is it?

Comment: @Frion3L If a forward-declared `class Foo` is used as an attribute, you have three options: making it a pointer `Foo *attr`, a reference `Foo &attr`, or a value `Foo attr`. It is only the third case when you must have a full include, because the compiler needs to know the structure of `Foo` in order to compute the size of the class in which `Foo attr` is an attribute.

Comment: @MichaelWild Your point about preventing rebuilds is definitely valid. However, its importance has dropped significantly in the last few decades. For example, some 15 years ago I worked for a company where avoiding a full rebuild has been essential: rebuilding on a developer's computer took 80 to 90 minutes, because our machines were several years old. Some 4 years later we got modern computers for development, and the time for a full rebuild went down to only two minutes. We continued to optimize our headers after that, too, but we did not spend nearly as much time doing it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Then I encourage you to build something like OpenFOAM or ParaView, or perhaps the full of KDE. That'll have your machine busy for a few hours for a full build.

Answer (score 2):

When you forward-declare a class:

```
class abc;
```

is becomes an [incomplete type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx), and there's only certain things that you can do with an incomplete type. For example, anything that requires the knowledge of the class's members, or even the knowledge of its size, would require a full declaration.

As to including headers from other headers, I can think of two arguments against:

1. Improved build times.
2. Fewer dependencies.

The first one may or may not be relevant depending on the size of your project, on your compiler, hardware etc. The second one is also questionable as it doesn't really reduce dependencies between classes.

One situation when you *have* to use a forward declaration is when you have a circular dependency between two classes defined in different headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
class abc;
```

When you forward declare a type the compiler treats it as an **Incomeplete type** and it does not have any information about the memory layout/composition of that type. So you cannot ask the compiler to perform any operation which requires it to know this information.

With Incomplete type you cannot:

- Use it to declare a member.
- Define functions or methods using this type.

But With Incomplete type you can:

- Declare a member to be a pointer to the incomplete type.
- Declare functions or methods which accepts/return incomplete types.
- Define functions or methods which accepts/return pointers to the incomplete type (but without using its members).

> **why is so bad to include so many headers in the .h file?**

It is bad because:

- Including a header merely copy pastes the contents of the header to current translation unit. This increases the compilation time as well as builds dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad to include many headers since if you change one of them you have to compile your file as well, which may not sound like a problem but for large programs compiling+linking can take a lot of time (sometime hours)

Answer (score 0):

All the compiler need to know is the name - not the composition - until it needs to generate the code.

So forward declaration is the way to go - as it does not require loading and parsing.

BTW - It helps that a makefile does not have to start recompiling stuff.